# List of matrices as arma object in the rcpp-function

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I am very new to Rcpp and have a question concerning definition of a list of matrices as arma object. I would like to speed up calculation of the likelihood function for a Hidden Markov Model with covariates in unobservable process. The following function in C++-code calculates the likelihood for a Hidden Markov Model without covariates in the process: the matrix gamma does not change over observations. It works.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double nLogLike_Rcpp(arma::mat ap, arma::mat gamma, arma::rowvec foo, int n)
{
        double lscale=0.0;
    int i=1;
    double sumfoo;

    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {       
        foo=foo*gamma%ap.row(i);
        sumfoo=sum(foo);
        lscale=lscale+log(sumfoo);
        foo=foo/sumfoo;
    }

    return lscale;
}
```

---

Here I have tried to write the function so that gamma is a list  of  n matrices where n is a number of observations, so that the transition probability matrix is different for each observation.  But I get an error-message if the code is running.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double nLogLike_Rcpp(arma::mat ap, Rcpp:: List gamma, arma::rowvec foo, int n)
{
        double lscale=0.0;
    int i=1;
    double sumfoo;

    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {


        gamma= Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(gamma[i])
        foo=foo*gamma%ap.row(i);
        sumfoo=sum(foo);
        lscale=lscale+log(sumfoo);
        foo=foo/sumfoo;
    }

    return lscale;
}
```

I would be very glad if anybody could help me to understand how to define the lists of matrices correctly.)))

UPD: This is the error message:

Error in sourceCpp("nLogLike_gamma.cpp") : 
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.

the piece of R-code where the C++ function is built in:

```
    #N=3: number of states
    Z<-length(hmmseries)
...
allprobs <- matrix(1,nrow=Z,ncol=N) ### Matrix with Z rows and N columns 

  ind <- which(!is.na(hmmseries)) 
  for (j in 1:N){
    allprobs[ind,j] <- dnorm(hmmseries[ind],mean=mu[j],sd=sigma[j])
  }




  foo <- delta%*%diag(allprobs[1,])### First alpha variable
  ll <- log(sum(foo))
  foo <- foo/sum(foo)



  ll <- nLogLike_Rcpp(allprobs, g, foo, Z) ### the rest variables calculated via Rcpp 

  #for(t in 2:Z){
  #  foo <- phi%*%g[[t]]%*%diag(allprobs[t,])  ####foo <- phi%*%g[[xneu$Hour[t-1]]]%*%diag(allprobs[t,])
   # ll <- ll+log(sum(foo))
   # phi <- foo/sum(foo)
   # lalpha[,t]<-ll+log(phi)
  #}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message? What you are passing to the function when you run it?

Comment: (1) have you tried changing `gamma= Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(gamma[i]);` to something like `arma::mat gamma_i = Rcpp::as<arma::mat>(gamma[i]);` ? Then of course you'd have to change `foo=foo*gamma%ap.row(i);` to `foo=foo*gamma_i%ap.row(i);` (2) Why do your loops start at `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`?

Comment: Also, I will say that this isn't great as far as a [mcve] goes. Could you edit your question to include some example input and output (could be trivially small instead of your intended use case)?

Comment: @duckmayr, thank you for the tip! It works.(But with the same speed as the normal R-Code:(  The loops start at i = 1 because the first element is already computed before the loop starts.